# ArrayList error, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, class, object, methods, arraylist

I'm very new to Java, and I seem to be getting some bizarre errors. I've looked everywhere for a solution, and all the solutions I've come across are identical to what I already have.

I've written a class to add a destination to an ArrayList, yet it's not working.

I'm getting this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Here's my code:

```
public void addDestination(String destination) {
    destinations.add(destination);
}
```

and the code for the data I'm trying to add to the ArrayList is this:

```
String temp = "test";
Agent smith = new Agent();
smith.addDestination(temp);
```

It quits the program in the method, and does not add the destination to the array list. Anyone got any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:

I'd initialised it to null in my default constructor, d'oh. Thanks everyone :-)**

Comment: Did you initialize `destinations`?

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code.

Comment: Where and how have you declared the arraylist?

Comment: Whatever the case, your list should be initialized to `new ArrayList<String>()`.

Answer (score 3):

A good practice in Java is to initialize your Collection to empty Collection instead of null in your default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

just initialize your list

```
List<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely did not initialize the ArrayList. The code would look something like:
    `destinations = new ArrayList<String>()`;